# Concurrent requests being sent to the tomcat dont match with Dynatrace JVM threads

Tags: tomcat, performance-testing, dynatrace

We are running performance test and using DynaTrace to monitor the run.
While performance team claims to be sending concurrent requests to the tune of 900 at one point of time.
I don't see that being reflected on the DynaTrace JVM threads .Is this the right place to check this ON DT or there is something wrong in the test itself. Also Jmeter shows all the requests to be successfull. Any pointers will be helpful

hosts->Processes ->JVM metrics
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why you're asking us and not the "performance team"? If you think that here you will get a more comprehensive answer you need to provide way more information like JMeter's [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) and report from its end.

1. Given there is a spike from 250 to 500 threads JMeter generates some load, why your app is not kicking off 900 threads it's another question, I can think of the situation when the application is using [Thread Pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) and it can serve the incoming requests without having to start as many threads as there are incoming connections
2. JMeter needs to be properly tuned for high loads so ask the "performance team" if they're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. JMeter treats [HTTP status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, if there is a logical error in the script, i.e. all threads are stuck at login screen and cannot go further JMeter will report the responses as "successful", it makes sense to check request/response details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in order to ensure that the test is doing what it is supposed to be doing. If it will turn out that it doesn't - consider adding i.e. [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)  to avoid such problems in the future
4. JMeter's workload pattern might be not properly configured on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level, the most common problem is that people forget to supply a sufficient amount of iterations, see [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for more information.